# dc.js to displaying start and end dates in the header / at the start of the dashboard

Tags: dc.js

I'm done building a dashboard using dc.js and i really need suggestions if there is a way to display the start and end date of the dashboard at the start of the dashboard. 

For ex: This dashboard displays the data from [dd-mon-yyyy] to [dd-mon-yyyy]. 
Considering the report start and end date field is available in the csv used for to build the dashboard.

Comment: This isn't really a dc.js question - just grab the start and end dates and use your favorite tools to update the div.